# Flask: Error when trying to get image file store in public folder - 404 Not Found

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, static-files

I tried to access static `image file` via link `localhost:5000/public/profile_img/b7b9661c-logo.png` that stored in `public` folder, but keep getting `404 Not Found`.

Anyone can guide me through this? I would really appreciate that.

**Project Structure**

```
+ public
   -profile_img
     -b7b9661c-logo.png
+ app
  - modules
     - init.py
```

****init**.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="/public")
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `Flask` is RESTful web services supported framework for python language.
So, you can't access static content directly using URL paths.

You can use following endpoint to fetch image from server :

Initial `init.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/image/download')
def get_image():
    return send_file(filename, mimetype='image/png')
```

For more information related [send_file](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file) function.